# package containing stb_image.h?

Tags: graphics

Have just moved some development from a Fedora system to Ubuntu, but I'm having a few problems.

I cannot find which package provides stb_image.h. On Fedora it was something starting stb or stbi, but nothing like that seems to exist with the synaptic package manager.

Can anyone point me to the right thing.

Thanks.

Comment: May [libsoil-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=stb_image) package be related (it has */usr/include/SOIL/stb_image_aug.h*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's been packaged by anybody, but you can always clone from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/nothings/stb.git
sudo cp stb/stb_image.h /usr/local/include/
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks done that. Works. Just a little suprised it's not available on Ubuntu, whereas it is with Fedora. Fedora are usually very picky about what they package.

Comment: Cool! If you wouldn't mind, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) since it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

There is a package now.

```
sudo apt install libstb-dev
```